# How to Run an Un-Built Source ASP.NET C# Website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web site using ASP.NET C# and I want to make changes on codes after publish. Every time I need to change something on a .cs file I have to build and publish web site then upload it to the server. Instead, I want to have a use like PHP style. Just make the changes on the source at server-side.

How can I do this if it is possible?

Comment: If you are usign IIS as a web server, you can host the site directly in IIS  instead of publishing. Just point the physical path of virtual directory to your application location.

Comment: _"I want to make changes on codes after publish"_ - that's your problem right there. Why can't you test your changes in your development environment?

Comment: How often do you change something? Is it just front or code behind stuff you change? Can't you just make it dynamic? You could just copy your project files to the web server and run it, but u lose all the compiler goodness. Why not use something like MSBuild so you just double click a batch file and it does the boring work like compiling and copying to server.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sometimes I need to change too little changes, maybe one word, but to do this I have to build all the web site again

Comment: @zkanoca there is a compiler option to leave the front end pages intact to allow editing - it will only put the code behind stuff into DLLs.... can't think what it is though grrr

Comment: @zkanoca: If you didn't precompile the web site then you can still change many things including the .aspx pages, the master pages, style sheets, javascript files and even web.config. However, you should never change your web site directly once it is published. It is really not a good practice.